# SQL server conditional unique constraint - Composite keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique-constraint, composite-key

I have a situation where i need to enforce a unique constraint on a set of columns, but only for one value of a column. Suppose there is a table named Person and columns 'Name' and 'isActive'
Following should be the results

```
INSERT INTO Person (name,isActive) VALUES ('testUser1',0); --Success
INSERT INTO Person (name,isActive) VALUES ('testUser1',1); --Success
INSERT INTO Person (name,isActive) VALUES ('testUser1',0); --Success
INSERT INTO Person (name,isActive) VALUES ('testUser1',1); --Failure
INSERT INTO Person (name,isActive) VALUES ('testUser1',0); --Success

INSERT INTO Person (name,isActive) VALUES ('testUser2',0); --Success
INSERT INTO Person (name,isActive) VALUES ('testUser2',1); --Success
INSERT INTO Person (name,isActive) VALUES ('testUser2',0); --Success
INSERT INTO Person (name,isActive) VALUES ('testUser2',1); --Failure
INSERT INTO Person (name,isActive) VALUES ('testUser2',0); --Success
```

Basically what I need is that same name and active=1 rows should not be repeated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a [filtered unique index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017):

```
create unique index index_name on Person (name) where isActive = 1
```